# Help: Python while loop inside Class

Tags: python

I'm just learning Python as my first programming language, and going through the [this online book](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex42.html).  My problem relates to the exercise found on that page.  I'm stuck understanding how the play method works inside the class.  How is it accessing all the other methods?  How is getattr functioning inside this loop?  Appreciate the help!

Here is the method for those that would prefer not to leave the page:

```
def play(self):
    next = self.start

    while True:
        print "\n--------"
        room = getattr(self, next)
        next = room()
```

Comment: You really are learning Python the hard way. ;-) I suggest using the official [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/).

Comment: @Keith I disagree. The hard way is easier ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to explain how it works.
First, this is run:

```
a_game = Game("central_corridor")
```

This calls `Game.__init__("central_corridor")`.
In the __init__ method, `self.start` takes the value "central_corridor".
Then we go back to the main body. By now, we have a variable called `a_game`. This variable is in fact an instance of the class `Game`, and it has some properties, like `a_game.start`, `a_game.quips`, `a_game.death()`, etc.
Next, this is run:

```
a_game.play()
```

That calls the `play()` method in `a_game`. Not in `Game`, but in `a_game`. Thus, when the method is running, it has access, through the word `self` (which is treated like a regular argument), to all properties of `a_game`.

This is run next

```
next = self.start
```

`self.start` was defined in `__init__()`, and is equal to "central_corridor". So now, `next` is "central_corridor".
We enter the `while True:` loop, print some hypens, and call `getattr()`.
`getattr()` takes at least two arguments. The first one is an intsance of an object, in this case `self`, and the second one is the *name* of an attribute of that instance. In this case `"central_corridor"`.
So getattr looks for an attribute of self that is called "central_corridor", and it finds it, and returns it. Now, `room` is equal to `self.central_corridor`.
Next, `next = room()` is run. As room is currently equal to `self.central_corridor`, this:

```
next = self.central_corridor()
```

is actually run.

`self.central_corridor()` can return one of "death", "laser_weapon_armory" or "central_corridor". Let's say it returns "laser_weapon_armory". Now `next` is "laser_weapon_armory". We go back to the beginning of the loop. We print some hyphens again, get an attribute of self named "laser_weapon_armory", which happens to be `self.laser_weapon_armory`, and run it.
`self.laser_weapon_armory` can return "the_bridge" or "death". This time let's say it returns "death". Now `next` is "death". We go back to the beginning of the loop, print some hypens, get `self.death`, and run it.

All `self.death` does is print a random string from self.quips, and then `exit(1)`. The `exit` function, which is from the `sys` module, does just that. It terminates the program.

And that's pretty much it. I hope this helped.

Good luck learning Python the hard way!

Comment: Perfect explanation!  That clears up what I wasn't sure about.  That the value that is returned is returned to next.  Thanks for taking the time to explain so thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here:

http://effbot.org/zone/python-getattr.htm

Basically `getattr(self, next)` asks the `self` object to return the attribute named by `next`. For example if `next` is "abc" then it's like calling `self.abc`.

Answer (score 1):

Though I am uncertain as to why, it is clear that getattr() is executing whatever value is posessed in 'next'. Initially it is 'start' which is '"central_corridor". However, after that function completes and returns a value, the interaction between room() and getattr(self, next) is picking up that value and executing the corresponding function as 'next'.

EDIT:

getattr() is getting the value of the attribute, rather than the attribute itself. The value of the attribute is.... *drum roll* whatever the attribute **returns**. Which requires the attribute to fully execute in order for the value to be obtained. Then, the attribute 'next' is changed to become the **return** of the now-executed attribute... 'next' is then run in order to get it's value by getattr() ! Repeat until 'death' or whatever, which breaks the cycle.

I get it now.

Comment: You are answering a question by saying "I'll answer this later."  Really?

Comment: Ok, was just testing out some ideas and I found that once the code hits return it then will exit out of the loop.  So if for example I reached return 'death' as in the first option after 'central_corridor' then it would exit the loop.  How does this returned value of 'death' then get used to proceed to the method death?

Answer (score 0):

getattr is a built-in function from python. The play method is a method that belongs to the class Game.

While True means that the loop keeps going forever till you interrupt it.

What else don't you understand?

**EDIT:** Ig you create a new game : `g = Game()`
then you can call the play method : `g.play()` , this is what play(self) means, you can also call it this way :`Game.play(g)`, but that is not common.

**EDIT2:** read more about getattr function [here](http://effbot.org/zone/python-getattr.htm)

Comment: Hmm, how can I explain.  I understand what you have said but I believe this is my problem.  I get that when Game() first runs, it goes through __init__ and then the play() method using central_corridor which it then runs.  What I don't understand is at the end of the method when it returns 'something' where does this 'something' get returned to and where does this goto inside the loop that is still running?  I guess how does the loop allow all the methods to be accessed?  Hope that's clear....I have only been learning programming for a week :D

Comment: so if I understand the question correctly, this play function has a return None there when no return type is specified , the while loop runs forever till you interrupt it, on every iteration it prints "---------" , gets a new value for variable room, and sets next to that value.

Comment: Remember that this is not a program, this is a class definition so you call these methods when you run idle or any other IDE and create a game instance and call the method play on it for example.

Comment: Yes, this is just the section of program that I'm stuck on but the whole exercise program is found on my link.  I just pulled out the part that I don't understand...

Answer (score 0):

It's actually very simple. :)

Think about it this way. `next` is assigned the reference (address) of `self.next`. So when we `getaddr(self, next)`, since next is the reference of `self.next`, it really is just asking for the memory address of `self.next` which is of course an attribute of `self`, so it works.

I know it looks a little odd though.

A simple example for you:

```
>>> a = 'r'
>>> print '0x%x' % id(a)
0x7fbe99e204b8
>>> b = a
>>> print '0x%x' % id(b)
0x7fbe99e204b8

>>> class T(object): pass
... 
>>> foo = T()
>>> print '0x%x' % id(foo)
0x15c6bd0
>>> bar = foo
>>> print '0x%x' % id(bar)
0x15c6bd0
>>> bar = T()
>>> print '0x%x' % id(bar)
0x15c6b90
```

So basically assigning a variable to another variable just references the same object, without changing anything.